# auth0 Management Api NextJs not able to update metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, auth0

Really struggling to get my head around authO management clients so I can update users information. I've created a Next.js API route for the backend but I'm not sure how to actually amend the user's data. I've followed the docs and got to the point below.

**API route**

The ID params I manually entered to test and my response is an empty JSON object.

The docs don't make it clear what I'm suppose to do in the update user area in.

```
var ManagementClient = require("auth0").ManagementClient;

export default async (req, res) => {
  var auth0 = new ManagementClient({
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL,
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope: "read:users update:users",
  });
  var params = { id: "**************************" };
  var metadata = {
    foo: "bar",
  };

  auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(params, metadata, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error.
    }

    // Updated user.
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200).json({ user });
  });
};
```

Error:

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/authapi, this may result in stalled requests.
   SanitizedError [APIError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http
   (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
      statusCode: 'ENOTFOUND',
      requestInfo: { method: 'post', url: '***********' },
      originalError: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http
          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
        errno: -3008,
        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'http',
        response: undefined
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? As in `console.log(err)`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky added the errors

Comment: Is `/api/authapi` the nextjs api path you are calling in your components?

Comment: Did other api method works ?

Comment: You probably should share how you set up the file structure for the api route and how you are calling it exactly when this error occurs.